# Background icon image and caption text are not aligned vertically

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Plunker code is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DhPuCysGhB3oqNuyThin).

I am trying to create a dropdown with an icon in the front. I am facing an issue where the vertical alignment for icon is good but for the caption, the text is displayed below the middle line as,

[image]

The caption `Select One` is below the middle line. How can i move it up, so that it is at same level as the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an item is `inline-block` and not `float`ing you may use `vertical-align: middle`.

It seems you are using a CSS framework and it is `float`ing, then you can use `line-height: #replace this with height of the icon in px#`, given that icon height is fixed. Use `line-height` to center text vertically with something that is taller than it.

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OyDOtj0hFnZFfsfZnDmS?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Please update the following code in your css..

```
.grouped-list-btn-content > .grouped-list-text {
    margin-top: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a margin-top on the text of 9px:

```
.grouped-list-btn-content > .grouped-list-text {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
```

change it to 5px:

```
.grouped-list-btn-content > .grouped-list-text {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Groups list text in your css file:

```
.grouped-list-btn-content   > .grouped-list-text {
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-top: 9px;
}
```

Change the amount in margin top for example 5 should make it more centered.